# hyperledger fabric,ECDSA verification failure

Tags: node.js, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

> [client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error:
>   Failed to deserialize creator identity, err The supplied identity is
>   not valid, Verify() returned x509: certificate signed by unknown
>   authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure"
>   while trying to verify candidate authority certificate
>   "ca.org1.example.com")

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this problem? What are you trying to achieve? And perhaps some code to give more context to your situation.

Comment: What exactly you trying to do? And what is your questions?

Comment: Any update on this, how to resolve the above error?

Comment: I believe it may be the result of a failed chaincode instantiation (at least that's what brought me here).

Comment: This can happen if you use a Hyperledger Fabric client version that's different to the server (peer) versions - for example, 2.2.1 and 2.1.1.  Fixed when client downgraded to match server.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly related to wrong certificates. Cross check the certificates, if possible generate certificates for CA again using cryptogen and accordingly place the certificates in peers.